# IIS 8.5 - Should SNI be enabled on all sites with SSL?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, iis-8.5, sni

I have a web server with IIS 8.5 and four sites setup. All sites are set up with SSL and are running from the same IP, with port 443 and have each their own host header. Three of the sites are using a wildcard cert, and one has it's own cert.

I was under the impression that when using multiple SSL cert's on the same server, and configuring sites to use the same ip and port #, that you needed to enable SNI for this to work properly.

An issue that we had with a application just recently has me questioning this thou. We have an application that is part desktop app, and part web based application. The desktop app, makes a call to a webservice on the website to generate some reports.

I originally had SNI enable on all 4 sites, but this seemed to cause a problem in the desktop application when calling the webservice. If i disabled SNI from the site with it's own certificate (not the wildcard cert), everything started working.

Also it's worth mentioning that the web service isn't even on the site that i had to disable SNI on. It's on one of the ones with the wild card cert.

If I used any of the 4 websites while SNI was enabled on all site, everything seemed to work fine on these sites. The problem really only seemed to be comming from the desktop app. When it called the webservice I would simply get a message that i tried to call some method in the webservice and that the connection was reset.

So I guess what i'm wondering is this:

- Is SNI supposed to be enable on all sites with SSL?
- Are you supposed to have one "Default site" running without SNI?
- Is the fact that the desktop app didn't work unless one site had SNI Checked off, points of a problem with that application?
- If I where to use the same wildcard SSL cert on all site, i'm assuming that i would even need to use SNI, since it's really for scenarios where you have multiple sites with different certs...is that correct?

Comment: It is too broad to discuss, as most answers can be super clear once you understand the background https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background and then review what certificate mappings are there on your machine. In general, use SNI whenever possible.

Comment: I cannot answer your question, but I recently had a bad experience when a website was REMOVED from an IIS server, and this caused a DIFFERENT website to fail : https connections from a well-known payment provider stopped working, even though no change was made to the website in question. I don't know exactly why it stopped working, but it appeared to be related to SNI.